# Sending HTTP requests from App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is it possible to send HTTP requests from my AppEngine application? I need to make some requests and pull some data from the other sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  More info here:  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html

> You can use the Python standard
>   libraries urllib, urllib2 or httplib
>   to make HTTP requests. When running in
>   App Engine, these libraries perform
>   HTTP requests using App Engine's URL
>   fetch service, which runs on Google's
>   scalable HTTP request infrastructure.

Here's an example:

```
import urllib
from xml.dom import minidom
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

params = urllib.urlencode({'p': loc_param, 'u': units,})
full_uri = '?'.join([url, params,])

result = urlfetch.fetch(full_uri)
if result.status_code == 200:
    return minidom.parseString(result.content)
```

Comment: You can also use urllib and urllib2 directly; they're patched to use the urlfetch service for you.