# Google App Engine (GAE) cron on external url: http

Tags: google-app-engine, url, cron

I try to use GAE for a cron job. But I get a server error 500.
Is it because I try to cron on a external url? I cannot find any documentation on this. When I use an internal URL it works fine. But I would like to cron job a php script on my website.

Is there another way to do this? I am quite noob...

Thanks for any help
Christian

This is my code:

http://www.mysite.com/apps/pushthis.php
    Trigger notifications for project
    every 2 minutes

Comment: Changed the three tags google, app, engine to google-app-engine, the standard AppEngine tag. Should get this question better notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make this work very simply. Create a small AppEngine application that answers a URL that will be called by the AE cron. That request handler can use the [URL Fetch API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) to call your external URL. A *tiny* little bit of extra work, but you will accomplish your goal.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834687/sending-http-requests-from-app-engine) for more information and practical examples of coding with URL Fetch.